# Access a static member of a class through an object

Tags: c++, class, static-members

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [accessing static member variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325607/accessing-static-member-variables)

I have a symbol `inst` which is an object of class `classy`. I need to access a static member of this class through the object’s symbol. I have tried `inst::staticmember` but my g++ says `error: ‘inst’ is not a class or namespace`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You use the dot:

```
inst.staticmember
```

`::` is only for use with namespaces or classes, as you may have discerned from your compiler error.

You can access static member variables two ways: either through `classy::staticmember` where `classy` is a class, or `inst.staticmember` where `inst` is a class instance.

Comment: I don’t know why I did not try that. Thanks. lol

Comment: I have to say, coming from Java, this looks illegal.